# Every set $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ of positive measure is the disjoint union of two sets $E = B \cup C$ such that $\mu(B) = \frac12\mu(E) = \mu(C)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $E \subset \Re$ be measurable with $\mu(E) > 0$. Show that there
>   are disjoint sets $B$ and $C$ such that $E=B \cup C$ and $\mu(B) =
>   \mu(C) = \frac12\mu(E)$.

Solution:

Assume $\mu(E) = \infty$. $f(t) = \mu(E \bigcap (-\infty, t))$.

$\lim\limits_{t \rightarrow -\infty} f(t) = 0$

$\lim\limits_{t \rightarrow \infty} f(t) = \mu(E)$

Somewhere in between is $\frac12\mu(E)$.

Comment: Can you show that $f$ is continuous? And why are you assuming that $\mu(E)=\infty$?

Comment: Ok, the first thing that I should do is prove continuity? 

So, I should also provide a solution for when $0 < \mu(E) < \infty$?

Comment: Yes. You can als tro to directly prove a kind of intermediate value theorem for your function.

Comment: There is an argument in a more general setup here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254728/simpler-proof-non-atomic-measures/276889#276889

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\mu(E)<+\infty$, then consider function $f(t)=\mu(E\cap(-\infty,t))$. Then 
$$
\lim\limits_{t\to-\infty}f(t)=0\qquad\qquad\lim\limits_{t\to+\infty}f(t)=\mu(E)\tag{1}
$$ 
Note that for $t_1<t_2$ we have $|f(t_2)-f(t_1)|=\mu(E\cap([t_1,t_2))\leq\mu([t_1,t_2))=t_2-t_1$. Hence $f$ is Lipschitz function, and as a consequence continuous. Then using $(1)$ we conclude that there exist $t_0\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(t_0)=0.5\mu(E)$. It remains to set $B=E\cap(-\infty,t_0)$, $C=E\setminus B$.

If $\mu(E)=+\infty$. Consider the sets $E_n=E\cap[n,n+1)$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$. These sets are disjoint sets of finite measure whose union is $E$. From the previous case we have for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ a pair of disjoint sets $B_n$, $C_n$ such that $E=B_n\cup C_n$ and $\mu(B_n)=\mu(C_n)=0.5\mu(E_n)$. Now consider 
$$
B=\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty B_n\qquad\qquad C=\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty C_n
$$
It is easy to check that they are disjoint and $E=B\cup C$, $\mu(B)=\mu(C)=\infty=0.5\mu(E)$.