# When does a measurable function exist with a given distribution?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

Let's suppose (A,X,P) and (B,Y,Q) are two probability spaces (A,B underlying spaces, X,Y sigma-algebras, P,Q probability measures, respectively).

Under what (topological and/or measure theoretic) conditions on these two spaces does there exist a measurable map M: A -> B
such that

P(M in b) = Q(b)   for an arbitrary element b of Y.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Do you mean that $b$ is an element of $Y$? There's no guarantee at the outset that singletons of $B$ are in $Y$

Comment: Yes I do. Thanks :)

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong I take it to mean that $b$ is an element of the $\sigma$-algebra $Y$, not an element of the underlying space $B$.

Comment: And P(M in b) means $P(M^{-1}(b))$?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A sufficient condition is that $(B,\mathcal{Y})$ is a Polish (separable and completely metrizable) space with its Borel $\sigma$-algebra and $(A,\mathcal{X},P)$ is atomless.

This result is widely known, but it hard to find an exact reference for it. It follows from Proposition 9.1.2 and Theorem 13.1.1 in Dudley 2004, *Real Analysis and Probability* for the case that $A=[0,1]$, $\mathcal{X}$ the Borel sets and $P$ the uniform distribution (Lebesgue measure). Now on every atomless probability space, one can find a uniformly distributed random variable with values in $[0,1]$. I will sketch a proof of this below.

It is possible to generalize the result above slightly and allow for $(B,\mathcal{Y})$ to be a Souslin space with its Borel $\sigma$-algebra. To get this as a corollary to the previous result, use Theorem 9.1.5 in Bogachev 2006, *Measure Theory*.

**Lemma:** Let $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$ be an atomless probability space. Then there is a random variable $f:\Omega\to [0,1]$ with $\mu\circ f^{-1}$ being the uniform distribution.

Proof: Using that finite atomless measures have [convex range](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254728/simpler-proof-non-atomic-measures), we can construct a sequence of independen random variables $(g_n)$ with $g_n:\Omega\to\{0,1\}$ that put equal probability on both numbers. This induces a random variable $g:\Omega\to\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ with fair coin-flipping measure as its distribution. The function $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}\ni(x_n)\mapsto\sum_n x_n/2^n$ is measurable and composing it with $g$ provides us with $f$.

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot, this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: It's absolutely clear to me that on any non-atomic probability space, there is a $\mathcal U_{[0,\:1]}$-distributed random variable. But how can we conclude that there is a $B$-valued random variable $M$ on $(A,\mathcal X,\operatorname P)$ with $M_\ast\operatorname P=Q$? Asked for that [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3061032/if-%ce%a9-a-text-p-is-a-non-atomic-prob-space-and-%ce%bc-is-a-prob-measure-on-a-b). That's only clear to me when $(B,\mathcal Y)=(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$.

Comment: @NateEldredge Don't get it. Isn't it the target space we're assuming to be Borel? Why should $(\Omega,\Sigma)$ be Borel?

Comment: @0xbadf00d The term is "standard Borel", a measurable space from which one can find a measurable bijection with measurable inverse onto $[0,1]$ with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker And why is every non-atomic probability space standard Borel? And how do you conclude the existence of $M$ in the question?

Comment: @0xbadf00d They are not. But every Polish space is standard Borel.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Could you point out how you conclude the existence of $M$?

Comment: @0xbadf00d Note the reference to Dudley's book.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Sorry, maybe I'm too stupid, but I still don't get how you conclude. It's clear to me that if $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ is a probability space on which there is a $\mathcal U_{[0,\:1]}$-distributed random variable $X$ and $F:\mathbb R\to[0,1]$ is any distribution function, then $F$ is the distribution function of $Y:=F^{-1}(X)$. However, how does this help here, where the target measure is defined on an arbitrary measurable space (and hence has no distribution function)?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: No, you're right.  I had mixed up the domain and codomain.  I removed the comment.

Comment: @NateEldredge Don't worry, it's easy to mix them up here. Do you have any idea how we can conclude [(see my question)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3061032/if-%ce%a9-a-text-p-is-a-non-atomic-prob-space-and-%ce%bc-is-a-prob-measure-on-a-b)? What I'm actually after is the existence of a coupling in terms of random variables: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2973927/successful-couplings-and-total-variation-convergence-to-equilibrium-for-time-hom

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker : I don't understand your proof either, are you sur about it ?

Comment: @CechMS Yes. Is there a specific point that is unclear?

Comment: First of all. [9.1.2] For any distribution function $F$, $X_{F}$ is a random variable with the distribution function $F$.

Comment: [13.1.1] If $X$ and $Y$ are two separable metric spaces which are Borel subsets of their completions then $X ~ Y$ if and only if $X$ and $Y$ have the same cardinality, which moreover is either finite, countable, or c (the cardinal of the continum).

Comment: [9.1.5] Let $X$ and $Y$ two Souslin spaces and let $f : X \rightarrow Y$ be a borel mapping such that $f(X) = Y$. Then, for every Borel measure $\nu$ on $Y$, there exists a Borel measure $\mu$ on $X$ such that $\nu = \mu \circ f^{-1}$ and $\| \mu \| = \| \nu \|$. If $f$ is a one to one mapping, then $\mu$ is unique.

Comment: Now the problem is : Let $(A,\mathcal{X},P)$ an atomless probability space, $(B,\mathcal{Y}, \mu)$ a polish space. We would like to show that it exists a mesurable function $h : A \rightarrow B$ such as $h \text{#} P = \mu$.

Comment: What is your first step please ?

Comment: @CechMS We reduce the problem to the case in which $B$ is the real line using [13.1.1]. Then we construct a uniformly distributed random variable $f:A\to [0,1]$, which is what I have sketched. Then we construct a random variable $g:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}=B$ with distribution $\mu$ when $[0,1]$ is endowed with the uniform distribution using [9.1.2]. Then $g\circ f$ does the trick.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I have some questions.

Comment: 1) How to be sur that the cardinality of $B$ is $c$ ? Maybe we could just add this hypothesis because a polish space can be discret.

Comment: 2) How do you construct $g_{n}$ in your $\mathbf{Lemma}$ ?

Comment: @CechMS If the Polish space is countable, it is already isomorphic to a Borel subset of $[0,1]$. To construct $g_n$. Split up the probability space into two pieces of equal measure, let $g_1$ be $1$ on one of the pieces and $0$ on the other. Then split up each of these pieces again into two pieces of equal measure and let $g_2$ be 1 on one of the subpieces and 0 on the other. Continuing this way gives you the desired random variables.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95411/discussion-between-cechms-and-michael-greinecker).

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker : I worked on the Linderstrauss proof of Lyapounov theorem. I proved your lemma, existence of $g_{n}$ and of the uniform random variable on $[0,1]$. I just have to work on Borel isomorphis now to fully understand the proof.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker : I have some questions.

Comment: 1) How to relax the assumption atomless ? The result is obviously false in the case. For exemple if $X = Y = \{0,1\}$, $\mu = 1/3 \delta_{0} + 2/3 \delta_{1}$, $\nu = 1/2(\delta_{0} + \delta_{1})$ then there is no such application. But it's easy to solve the transport problem between discret measure so maybe we can say something general ?

Comment: 2) Can we generalize it to non finite measure ? For exemple we can do it between two measures which are absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure.

Comment: There are various ways and sets of assumptions to do so, but I have no special idea.