# If $(Ω,A,\text P)$ is a non-atomic prob. space and $μ$ is a prob. measure on a Borel space there is a variable on $(Ω,A,\text P)$ with law $μ$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a non-atomic probability space
- $(E,\mathcal E)$ be a Borel space
- $\mu$ be a probability measure on $(E,\mathcal E)$

> How can we show that there is a $(\mathcal A,\mathcal E)$-measurable $X:\Omega\to E$ with $X_\ast\operatorname P=\mu$ (pushforward measure)?

I know that if $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R),\nu)$ is a non-atomic probability space, the distribution function $F$ of $\nu$ is continous and $F_\ast\nu=\mathcal U_{[0,\:1]}$ (uniform distribution).

> Now, I'll assume that for all $B\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$, $(B,\mathcal B(B))$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$ (i.e. there is a measurable bijection between $(B,\mathcal B(B))$ and $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$ with measurable inverse). Does anyone have a reference for that claim?

By that assumption, there is a $\mathcal U_{[0,\:1]}$-distributed random variable on any non-atomic probability space $(B,\mathcal B(B),\nu)$ with $B\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$.

$(E,\mathcal E)$ being Borel implies that $(E,\mathcal E)$ is isomorphic to $(B,\mathcal B(B))$.

> How can we conclude? [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/662806/47771) seems to claim that the desired conclusion is possible, but I don't get how we need to argue exactly.

Comment: See 'A course on Borel sets' by Srivastava and 'Measure Theory' by Cohen.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Do you have a specific section in mind?

Comment: There are several isomorphism theorems in measure theory and the they are quite deep. You will, have to spend quiet a bit of time to digest these. I suggest you first look at statements of some of these theorems from Cohen's book first.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Your comment is only related to the isomorphism between $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$ and $(B,\mathcal B(B))$ I've asked for, right? If so, do you have any idea how we need to proceed once this existence is known?

Comment: Hi 0xbadf00d ! I asked the same question. Did you find an answer ? (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3234483/pushforward-measure)