# Totally Cool Proof of Sierpinski's Theorem?

Tags: measure-theory

Talking about

> > **Theorem.** If $\mu$ is a non-atomic measure on $X$ and $0<t<\mu(X)$ then there exists $E$ with $\mu(E)=t$.

The proofs I see all use Zorn's lemma or transfinite recursion. Don't get me wrong, I think the proof by transfinite recursion is simple, natural and elegant: We try to construct $E$ as a union of sets with small measure. After we have $\omega$ of them it may be that the measure of the union is still less than $t$, so we just go ahead and "define" $E_\alpha$ for countable ordinals $\alpha$, and for some countable $\alpha$ we must have $\mu\left(\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}E_\beta\right)=t$. (One could easily convert that to a proof by Zorn's lemma that seems simpler and more natural than the Zorn proofs I've seen: Consider a maximal collection $(E_\alpha)$ of disjoint sets of positive measure with $\sum\mu(E_\alpha)\le t$...)

So that's nice and "intuitive", but it seems like there "should" be a more elementary argument. [There is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3322079/sequence-that-converges-in-l2-on-the-real-line-but-nowhere-pointwise/3322108#3322108) a proof using nothing but epsilons and deltas, although it's a little bit complicated. (I kinda like the proof of the Main Lemma there; it's clear  that the ML is something tending in the direction of the theorem, and indeed the proof of the theorem from ML is straightforward.)

Anyway, my **question** is whether anyone sees how to make the following proof work:

**Totally Cool Proof.** Let $A$ be the "measure algebra", that is, the space of equivalence classes of measurable sets modulo null sets. Define a metric on $A$ by $d(E,F)=\mu(E\Delta F)=||\chi_E-\chi_F||_1$ (say we're in the case $\mu(X)<\infty$.) Then $(A,d)$ is connected (because **why?**), hence $\mu(A)$ is connected.

**Note** I tend to believe that $(A,d)$ is in fact path-connected, because it seems to me that a limit of successive refinements of the chain obtained in proof of the $\frac12$theorem at that link should give a path. But no points for working that out; what I'm wondering about is a totally trivial proof that there are no non--trivial clopen sets...

Comment: @Bernard Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

It is true that $(A,d)$ is path-connected, but proving it involves the same ideas that you need to prove Sierpinski's theorem directly.

In fact, even though it is not actually phrased this way, this is essentially [how Sierpinski's theorem is proven on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_%28measure_theory%29#Non-atomic_measures). More precisely, they give a slick proof (using Zorn's lemma) of the following strong form of Sierpinski's theorem:

> **Proposition:** For any $B\in \Sigma$ with $\mu(B)=c$, then there exist a monotone function $s: [0,c]\to \Sigma$ with $s(c)=B$ which is a right inverse to $\mu$ (namely $\mu(s(t))=t$).

Then $s$ is a continuous path between $\emptyset$ and $B$ (in fact, it is an isometric embedding), which shows the path-connectedness of your metric space.