# Measure theory texts with a longer exposition toward the beginning on atomic and nonatomic measures?

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request

The popular texts on Measure Theory that I know of (as well as sone probability texts I have), such as Royden, Folland, and Halmos, seem to not address topics such as atoms, atomic measures, or nonatomic measures other than maybe a page of explanation, or they may just throw such topics in an exercise or two.

I am looking for a textbook to supplement the one-page explanation on Atomic and Nonatomic Measures (section 3.5) in Dudley's *Real Analysis and Probability*. The textbook should introduce these topics toward the beginning with the intro measure theory sections, around the time when Lebesgue measure is introduced.

Are there any suggestions for such a text? I am particularly looking for more than just defining what atomic/nonatomic measures simply *are*: I am seeking some exposition on theorems as well.

Comment: Have you seen Fremlin's 5-volume treatise? https://www1.essex.ac.uk/maths/people/fremlin/mt.htm

Comment: @Unit Thanks, I haven't until now. I'd say Volume 2 is more extensive on its treatment of such concepts, but not by much. Results such as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254728/simpler-proof-non-atomic-measures) I've had a very hard time finding in textbooks.